# Difference between passing string "0x30" and hexadecimal number 0x30 to hex() function

Tags: perl, decimal, hex

`print hex("0x30");` gives the correct hex to decimal conversion.

What does 
`print hex(0x30);` mean?
The value it's giving is 72.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`hex()` takes a string argument, so due to Perl's weak typing it will read the argument as a string whatever you pass it.

The former is passing `0x30` as a string, which `hex()` then directly converts to decimal.

The latter is a hex number `0x30`, which is 48 in decimal, is passed to `hex()` which is then interpreted as hex again and converted to decimal number 72. Think of it as doing `hex(hex("0x30"))`.

You should stick with `hex("0x30")`.

```
$ perl -e 'print 0x30';
48
$ perl -e 'print hex(0x30)';
72
$ perl -e 'print hex(30)';
48
$ perl -e 'print hex("0x30")';
48
$ perl -e 'print hex(hex(30))';
72
```

Comment: hex always interprets its argument as a string, so passing a number just seems like a way to create confusion to me :)

Comment: +1:  Note that 48 is passed to `hex`, which stringifies its argument, and interprets the resulting "48" as a hex number equivalent to decimal 72.  It is the stringification that is important.  But good diagnosis...

Comment: @hobbs Ok, I'll change my answer to pass a string.

Comment: but i'm not having this confusion when using hex(30) and hex("30") both are giving the same value. why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on marcog's answer: From [`perldoc -f hex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html)

> hex EXPR: Interprets EXPR as a hex string and returns the corresponding value.

So hex really is for conversion between string and hex value. By typing in 0x30 you have already created a hex value.

```
perl -E '
  say 0x30;
  say hex("0x30");
  say 0x48;
  say hex(0x30);
  say hex(hex("0x30"));'
```

gives

```
48
48
72
72
72
```

Comment: By 12 minutes, don't you check other answers before posting? :)

Comment: @marcog you posted, then edited while I was typing. I saw the new post by Simon while I did it, but I guess it doesn't warn of edits while entering an answer like it does for new answers.

Answer (score 2):

`hex()` parses a hex string and returns the appropriate integer.

So when you do `hex(0x30)` your numeric literal (0x30) gets interpreted as such (0x30 is 48 in hex format), then hex() treats that scalar value as a string ("48") and converts it into a number, assuming the string is in hex format. 0x48 == 72, which is where the 72 is coming from.